# How to write multiple where clauses in one request while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Error in my query:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`name`, b.`email` 
FROM `table_1` a, `table_2` b 
WHERE a.`id`, b.`id` = 5
```

Comment: `a.id = 5 and b.id = 5` ;).

Comment: or 
SELECT a.`id`, a.`name`, b.`email` FROM `table_1` a, `table_2` b on a.`id`= b.`id` where a.`id`= 5

Comment: @zahiromor (join)

Comment: What do you mean by multiple where clause in one line while join two table? is it two or more conditions in where clause? Please write more specific and descriptive question. Thanks

Comment: @houynarun I'm sorry but the question is completely obvious

Comment: The "WHERE clause" is the whole section beginning with `where`, and you can only have one of them. However you can add conditions using `and` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are trying to find details for id 5 and hence your query should use:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`name`, b.`email` 
FROM `table_1` a INNER JOIN `table_2` b 
ON   a.`id` = b.`id`
WHERE a.`id` = 5
```

Please note implicit joins are discouraged and you need to start using ANSI.